# Property of my MvcApplication is null when accessing it from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC so I'm having a little trouble with this one. When the application start, I set a property to a certain value. Yet when I try to access this property in a controller (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066350/how-to-get-mvcapplication-instance-in-asp-net-controller)), the property is always null.

Is it something I am misunderstanding?

Here a simplified version of the code :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    internal ExtensionManager Extensions { get; private set; }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        this.Extensions = new ExtensionManager();
    }
}

public ActionResult ListExtension()
{
    var app = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as MvcApplication;
    return View(app.Extensions.InstalledExtensions);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple `HttpApplication` instances created throughout the application lifecycle but `Application_Start` is only called once when the application first initialises.

See this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx

I don't know what you are trying to store here (extensions?) but if its global to all users then you could use a static property, otherwise store it somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer (but for anyone in need of assistance).

I had this issue as well.

I think you can use the `Application["myKey"]` array, to set some values. Sure they aren't instance properties, but you can set a dependency injection container (like unity, who recommends this option in their code sample) , then access it from your controller with `Application["myKey"]`.

> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set
>   any instance data because it will be available only to the first
>   instance of the HttpApplication class that is created.