# How to access instance properties of MvcApplication class inside request context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Inside controller action you can:**

```
MvcApplication app = this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as MvcApplication;
```

But `this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance` only holds the superclass, **not the derived class** declared in Global.asax. Therefore any instance properties you declared there, are null;

**Is there a way around this? Shouldn't there be a way to access the derived app class?**

I'd like to have instances (of my helper classes), stored as instance properties inside the application instance, rather than having them as static classes.

**Or do static helpers, hold no drawbacks?**

Comment: Is it instance of MvcApplication is null or its properties are null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer (but for anyone in need of assistance).

I had this issue as well.

I think you can use the Application["myKey"] array, to set some values. Sure they aren't instance properties, but you can set a dependency injection container (like unity, who recommends this option in their code sample) , then access it from your controller with Application["myKey"].

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx

> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set
>   any instance data because it will be available only to the first
>   instance of the HttpApplication class that is created.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way around this and you've already written it:

```
MvcApplication app = this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as MvcApplication;
```

If you don't like that, try changing your `MvcApplication` class to:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    public static MvcApplication Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Current could be null, depending on the caller
            return HttpContext.Current != null
                ? HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance
                : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access your application as `MvcApplication.Instance`. Be cautious that `Instance` is not null.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you may have missed the point? Although it casts it to MvcApplication, any instance property values are null because this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance only holds the superclass. (HttpApplication). And I don't see how the get accessor solves anything. (Sorry not trying to be rude)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Can you share the code that you are using? I use a similar pattern in my code and my member properties are not null. Are you saying that `this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as MvcApplication` is `null`? Otherwise, the *type* is the super class, but the *reference* is the `MvcApplication`.

Comment: I'll have a look and get back to you Ed!

Comment: Hi Ed, so referring to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305232/property-of-my-mvcapplication-is-null-when-accessing-it-from-a-controller/18691442#18691442, it looks as though it's because the Application instance is created several times, and thats why it appears as null. I'm not 100% on this. Anyway I post an answer on this question to anyone who is interested

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in using single static class, because your code becomes portable to non web project as well.

Ideally, instead of static properties, you can create MyApp class and wrap all app specific global data and other utility methods. And either you can create a static instance property and store instance of MyApp in HttpContext.Current.Application which is globally accessible in each request.

I think you are not aware that HttpApplication class is reused, and I suspect that your some handler is cleaning the properties.